# Annoying warning: Integer constant not in the range of enumerated type 'UIViewAnimationOptions'

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode

When writing code like the following in XCode 5 using clang set to C11/C++11:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
    animations:^{
        self.imgCheckIn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    completion:nil];
```

The `options` field generates the following warning:

```
integer constant not in range of enumerated type 'UIViewAnimationOptions' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationOptions') [-Wassign-enum]
```

The problem seems to be that the method takes a `UIViewAnimationOptions` type, which is just an enum of `NSUInteger`. However, OR'ing values together creates a value that isn't explicitly in the enum, so it complains.

In general this seems to be a nice kind of warning to have so I'd like to keep it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not able to recreate the error using Xcode 5, not sure what my clang is set to, but i've never changed it.

Comment: You probably aren't using the -Weverything flag.

Comment: This must have been fixed eventually within the past decade: I'm getting no similar warnings with `-Wassign-enum` enabled (and I'm definitely using a lot of boolean-or'd options). Edit: Looks like `NS_OPTIONS` enums now have the [`flag_enum`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#flag-enum) attribute set.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. As you already noticed, the compiler complains because the
value is none of the values defined in the enumeration. (The compiler flag `-Weverything` implies this check.)

You can suppress the warning either by an explicit cast:

```
options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat)
```

or with a `#pragma`:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wassign-enum"
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     self.imgCheckIn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hopping for a better solution :)

Comment: It seems like the explicit cast would be preferable in most cases, especially when the documentation/headers mention using a value not defined in the enumeration. Any good arguments for going with the `#prama` other than making the workaround stand out more?